# Help, In the middle of translating Python script to Scala

Tags: python, scala

I'm trying to translate: http://thinkstats.com/survey.py this script.

So here's what I'm translating right now (Python):

```
"""This file contains code for use with "Think Stats",
by Allen B. Downey, available from greenteapress.com

Copyright 2010 Allen B. Downey
License: GNU GPLv3 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
"""

import sys
import gzip
import os

class Record(object):
    """Represents a record."""

class Respondent(Record): 
    """Represents a respondent."""

class Pregnancy(Record):
    """Represents a pregnancy."""
```

Scala:

```
import sys.process._
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
import java.io._

class Record[T](val obj: T)

class Respondent[T](val record: Record[T])

class Pregnancy[T](val record: Record[T])
```

Question:
Did I do the `class Respondent` and the `class Pregnancy` correctly? Is the type annotation correct for these class? Is the logic correct? I've just read up on type parameterization so I'm a bit iffy on this and wanted to see if I'm on the correct path.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It may be correct -- I'm not sure. What does the type parameter `T` used for?

Comment: @Owen I dunno yet. I just know it's taking a parameter of type Object in. It might be a stream, so therefore I just annotate it as a type T. And when I declare Respondent and Pregnancy class, I get an error because Record takes a parameter, so I ended up annotating the Record type in Respondent and Pregnancy parameter. >____<

Comment: Usually you use a type parameter if there can be different kinds of that class, so, for example, you could have a `Record[Int]` be a record that holds an `Int`. I'm pretty sure it makes sense for `Record`, but I'm not sure about `Respondent` -- do different kinds of respondents have different kinds of records?

Comment: @Owen Hmmm... but you can't exactly do class Respondent(val record: Record) because Record actually needs to take in something. And having a fix [t] type of record actually solve this since I don't know what type of parameter Record is taking in yet..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I recall, the Python syntax you're showing is for *class extension* (inheritance). The equivalent Scala would be

```
/** Represents a record.
 */
class Record

/** Represents a respondent.
 */
class Respondent extends Record

/** Represents a pregnancy.
 */
class Pregnancy extends Record
```

Scala comments of the form `/** ... */` will show up as documentation in ScalaDoc.

Type parameterization isn't needed here. Its main use is to allow classes to accept or return values of an arbitrary parameterized type. For example, `List[Int]` and `List[String]` are lists of integers and strings respectively.

Comment: Thank you. Did a quick google to confirm this, very surprise/shock on how Python does inheritance.